# Roma Termini to CIA airport

Tags: italy, rome, cia

My flight is at 6.30 am from CIA airport, Italy. My hotel is in Rome (near Termini). Do I get public transport to go to the airport in the early morning?

Comment: define "early morning".

Answer (score 5):

The earliest you can get the train-bus combo is at 05:42, which is far too late for a 6:30am flight (arrival at 6:18).

---

You can take the [RomaAirportBus](https://romeairportbus.it/en/homepage-eng/) from Termini at 4:15, making you arrive at 4:55, which leaves you ~1h30 to board your flight